# How does JDK 6 regexp compare with org.apache.regexp?

Tags: java, java-6, regex

I'm interested in benchmarks and functionality? Is there are any reason to use Jakarta regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no reasons for that. But there are some other interesting libraries, apart from jakarta one. This link provides some information about performance and perl5 regexps compatibility:

http://tusker.org/regex/regex_benchmark.html